# Strongly typed viewdata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a strongly typed `LocationViewData` with a properties like

```
public Location location { get; set; }
```

`Location` itself is model, with the properties `Address`, `Country`, and so on.

In the controller I have:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    LocationViewData ld = new LocationViewData();
    ...
    return View(ld);
}
```

In the view codebehind I have:

```
public partial class Edit : ViewPage<MvcTest.Models.LocationViewData>
{
}
```

And my question is: how can I let the properties from a `Location` model in my `ViewData` to display in the appropriate textboxes, like:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("address") %>
```

I don't want to have to specify each field by its full name:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("address", ViewData.Model.location.address) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already works exactly like that. Start a new MVC (beta 1) project, and put this in the "Index" action of the "Home" controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        this.ViewData.Model = new MyObject
        {
            Name = "Timmy",
            FavColor = "Blue",
        };

        return View();
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string FavColor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, put this in the View:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("FavColor") %>
```

It'll say "Blue" in it. It tries to bind by the name already (MVC checks a few places, one of which is the "Model").

EDIT: What you need to do is:

1. Make sure that "location" is a property, and that "address" is a property.
2. put "location.address" as the name... not just "address".

Comment: about your 2th way, it will set name of text box is location.address, and when submit to controller, it can not map into "string address param" of controller method